# MySQL tables are empty after restarting Linux application

Tags: java, mysql, linux, persist

I am using hibernate to persist entity objects in a local running database.

Everything is working fine (connecting to the database, add/delete/update entries), as long as the application is running.

I am using this code to pass the entry to a table:

`CrudRepository:`

```
public interface ArticleRepository extends CrudRepository<ArticleEntity, Integer> {
}
```

`DB accessor method:`

```
public void addArticleEntity(ArticleEntity articleEntity){
    articleRepository.save(articleEntity);
}
```

After restarting the application all the entries are gone, only the empty table itself is persisted permanently.

How can I save these table entries permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for posting such random information, I simply had no idea where to start searching. Even tho, downvoting did not help.

The solution was to set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` (which obviously create new tables on restart) to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`.

Probably it'll help someone looking for similar terms.

Answer (score 0):

The persist method is intended for adding a new entity instance to the persistence context, i.e. transitioning an instance from transient to persistent state.

We usually call it when we want to add a record to the database (persist an entity instance):

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("John");
session.persist(person);
```

For more information:
https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate